# How do I fix a EReadError in Delphi 10.4?

Tags: delphi

I have an app to build in Delphi for a school project. The app is basically done, but every time I try to run the app this error keeps occurring, and I don't know how to fix it.

This is the error message:

> Exception EReadError in module frmpitstop_p.exe at 0007A8F8.
> Error reading conPitStopDatabase.Mode: Invalid property value.

Please help.

[image]

I tried to declare `FormCreate` as `published` rather than `public`, but it did not help. Maybe I did it in the wrong place? I am not sure.

Comment: You should be able to debug your program and the debugger will stop on the line that is causing the issue.

Comment: Sounds like maybe your Form's DFM is corrupted. Right-click on the Form at design-time, choose View as Text, find and remove the offending property, then right-click and choose View as Form, and reconfigure the component as needed.

Comment: The debugger did not stop at the line so I don't know what the problem is. Just that there is an error.  How will know what the offending property is?